# amazon s3.upload is taking time

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to s3, before that I am altering the name of the file. Now I am accepting 2 files from request form-data object, renaming the filename, and uploading the file to s3. And end of the task I need to return the renamed file list which is uploaded successfully.

I am using `S3.upload()` function. But the problem is, the variable which is assigned as empty array initially, that will contain the renamed file list. But the array is returning empty response. The `s3.upload()` is taking much time. is there any probable solution where I can store the file name if upload is successful and return those names in response.

Please help me to fix this. The code looks like this,

```
      if (formObject.files.document && formObject.files.document.length > 0) {
        const circleCode = formObject.fields.circleCode[0];
        let collectedKeysFromAwsResponse = [];
        formObject.files.document.forEach(e => {
          const extractFileExtension = ".pdf";
          if (_.has(FILE_EXTENSIONS_INCLUDED, _.lowerCase(extractFileExtension))) {
            console.log(e);
            //change the filename
            const originalFileNameCleaned = "cleaning name logic";
            const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
            const s3FileName = "s3-filename-convension;
            console.log(e.path, "", s3FileName);
            const awsResponse = new File().uploadFileOnS3(e.path, s3FileName);
            if(e.hasOwnProperty('ETag')) {
              collectedKeysFromAwsResponse.push(awsResponse.key.split("/")[1])
            }
          }
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

use `await s3.upload(params).promise();` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest code - which is *AWS SDK for JavaScript V3*. Here is the code you should be using

```
// Import required AWS SDK clients and commands for Node.js.
import { PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { s3Client } from "./libs/s3Client.js"; // Helper function that creates Amazon S3 service client module.
import {path} from "path";
import {fs} from "fs";

const file = "OBJECT_PATH_AND_NAME"; // Path to and name of object. For example '../myFiles/index.js'.
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);

// Set the parameters
export const uploadParams = {
  Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
  // Add the required 'Key' parameter using the 'path' module.
  Key: path.basename(file),
  // Add the required 'Body' parameter
  Body: fileStream,
};


// Upload file to specified bucket.
export const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
    console.log("Success", data);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```

More details can be found in the [AWS JavaScript V3 DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html).